# What is the force between two points in space due to expansion of space between them?

Tags: relativity

Is there any way(equations?) to calculate the force between two points due to the expansion of the space between them?
(To clearify the question I should add that the reason we donot expand while the space between the particles in our body expanding is that there is inter atomic or intermolecular attractive force between them)

I am interested in the exact force due to expansion of space.
also see this ans, [What is the meaning of the "expansion of space"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95538/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-expansion-of-space/95575#95575)

Comment: From Hubble's law, $\dot{x}=Hx$, we get the acceleration $\ddot{x}=H^2x$.