# Does a photon travel more than 1 billion light years in 1 billion years due to the expansion of space?

Tags: photons, space-expansion

Assuming we shoot a photon out into space, it would go 1 light year after 1 year, and 1 million light years after 1 million years.

Because after that the expansion of space is noticeable, would photon be farther than 1 billion light years after 1 billion years?

Does the expansion of space (Hubble flow) carry the photon forward?

Comment: What is the age of the Universe? Compare with its size. You'll have your answer

Comment: I think in this way...Pressume an ant makes 10cm in 5sec on an noninflating baloon from A to B.If the baloon is an inflating one the distance from A to B in meantime  grows so it will not make it in 5sec but more...

Answer (score 0):

Technically the universe is not expanding into anything neither it affects the motion of the objects.Just the metric which governs the geometry of spacetime is stretching.So the photon is not going forward.

Comment: I'm only self-taught in cosmology, but I find this answer dubious.

Comment: @electronpusher which one??Expansion of metric? check it  [Link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95538/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-expansion-of-space?rq=1)

Comment: How is your claim that "the motion of the objects" is not affected consistent with cosmological redshift? If the expansion of space is not affecting photons as the travel, then how do we observed their wavelengths to be lengthened?

Comment: I think the idea is the expansion changes the amount of space between things, as opposed to moving the things. The question is does that apply to the photon?